# Can someone explain this piece of code that recognises a digit from the Coursera Machine Learning course

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

This is a snippet from the predict function of exercise 4 of the Coursera machine learning course. What it does is it stores the predicted digit from a trained neural network in p. Can someone explain how it does this?

```
    function p = predict(Theta1, Theta2, x)
    p = 0;
    h1 = sigmoid(double([1 x]) * Theta1');
    h2 = sigmoid([1 h1] * Theta2');
    [dummy, p] = max(h2, [], 2);
    end
```

`x` = 1x784 matrix of pixel intensity values.
`Theta1` = 100x785 matrix.
`Theta2` = 10x101 matrix.

I have already trained the network and have gotten the optimum value of Theta1 and Theta2. What I want to know is how that last line of code takes the forward propagated values and stores 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10 in p. Whichever digit is stored is the predicted digit.

Sigmoid function:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = 1 ./ (1 + e.^-z);
end
```

Comment: You definitely need to provide the rest of the function and also make your question more specific. At the moment it reads "how do you make a neural network recognise digits from handwriting" which is way to broad. Reword your question to ask something more specific about that code snippet and also provide the rest of the code because that snippet means nothing without information on what `x` and `Theta1` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line simply returns **index of the neuron with the highest value**, in matlab/octave

```
[M, I] = max(A, [], dim)
```

stores in `I` indeces of `A` which have highest values among dimension `dim`. In your case, `h2` has activations of each output neuron, and from construction of your neural network - classification is simply index of the one with the highest value,

```
cl(x) = arg max_i f_i(x)
```